# Onclick anywhere on page close popup - Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup.

I want to close popup when click anywhere on page close popup.

Here is my code fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/24/

Code :

```
$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({

    type: 'inline',
    modal: true,

});

$(document).on('click', '.closePopup', function (e) 
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.magnificPopup.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight adjustment ,check fiddle :)

> $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
>
> ```
> type: 'inline',
> modal: false,
> ```
>
> });

```
> $(document).on('click', '.closePopup', function (e) 
>             {
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                 $.magnificPopup.close();
>             });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/27/

Comment: Can you tell me that how can I call this popup to open from another function? Something Like this : jsfiddle.net/qweWa/29

Comment: ".ajax-call" is a class here.
$(".ajax-call").button().click(function(){ your code });

OR


If you want the function to run on click of a button,use this:
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

Comment: I cant post answer twice here,cuz it goes against the 1st question.(Which would look better)

Just accept my ans and provide a new question,then i can answer there.

But the answer is within the comment above i posted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `modal: false`

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denodir/qweWa/26/)

Comment: Can you tell me that how can I call this popup to open from another function?

Something Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/29/

Answer (score 0):

modal: When set to true, the popup will have a modal-like behavior: it won’t be possible to dismiss it by usual means (close button, escape key, or clicking in the overlay).

```
$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({

    type: 'inline',
    modal: false

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Magnific-Popup Documentation](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) There's actually **no need** to set `modal:false` *explicitly*. Which most of the answers have done.

If you go through the documentation you'll find that, If you don't even pass the modal attribute it work. I've edited [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmfakhon/) as per your requirement. I think unnecessary override a attribute can be avoided in this case.

Just these would be fine:

```
$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
});
```

Note: Don't forget to note the difference of this answer with another answers.